# XSD Simple type at the same time as complex type

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

I have the following schema

```
<xs:element name="a">
   <xs:complexType>
     <xs:choice>
       <xs:element ref="b"/>
       <xs:element ref="c"/>
     <xs:choice>
   </xs:complexType>
<xs:element/>
```

How can I achieve to a to be a simple element at the same time? I want to be able for  handle all cases below:

```
<a>TEXT</a>
<a><b/></a>
<a><c/></a>
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want a to be a complex type with elements b or c, but also possible to be just TEXT. This can be achieved by using a choice element.

Take a look at [this](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_choice.asp).
With minOccurs you can specify how many times you at least want this element to occur. Put it to 0 to make the field optional.

**EDIT:**
This is a solution, I tested it for the xml in the question and it works. You should use the mixed="true field"

```
<xs:element name="a">
<xs:complexType mixed="true">
    <xs:choice>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0"  ref="b"/>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" ref="c"/>
    </xs:choice>
    <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" />
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: Element 'a' cannot have character [children], because the type's content type is element-only.

Comment: Then I do not understand your question... You want the values of <a> to be TEXT, element b or element c, right?

Comment: shouldn't my edit part in the answer work? That's how I think I would do it.

Comment: The content of 'choice' must match (annotation?, (element | group | choice | sequence | 
 any)*). A problem was found starting at: simpleType.

Comment: Hmmmm, okay, so that doesn't work... Can you try should to declare a new element that consists of the simple type text which is of type xs:string, and add that element to the choice part. Does that help?

Comment: can you please check my answer then? that helps me build reputation :) just click the checkmark under the upvote count of my answer :) thanks :)

Comment: Note that the solution given will also allow text content alongside the b or c element: once you have declared something as mixed content, it can contain text anywhere.

Comment: And is there a way to block that? Or maybe a better solution at hand then mine?